# error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol despite inclusion of header file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, unresolved-external

I have a problem I can't seem to resolve. 
I have a file JobDispatcher.cpp which includes a file `#include "CalculateNormalsJob.h"`
containing the declaration of a class with the same name.

```
class CalculateNormalsJob : public Job
{

public:
    CalculateNormalsJob(some params);
...
};
```

The file CalculateNormalsJob.cpp contains the following definition

```
CalculateNormalsJob::CalculateNormalsJob(some params)
    : Job(params)
{
}
```

Both CalculateNormalsJob.h and CalculateNormalsJob.cpp are in the same project and folder as JobDispatcher.cpp which creates a Job object as

```
add(new CalculateNormalsJob(some params));
```

During linking, I receive the following error

```
Error   9   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall CalculateNormalsJob::CalculateNormalsJob(class ResourceMap *,class JobScheduler *,class Job *,int)" (??0CalculateNormalsJob@@QAE@PAVResourceMap@@PAVJobScheduler@@PAVJob@@H@Z)    C:\Fredrik\vs12\proflexa\scanner\JobDispatcherJob.obj
```

I am clueless as to what I have forgotten. I'm using Visual studio 2012 under Win7 and the included v110 compiler.

Any help appreciated!

EDIT:

For some reason it seems like `CalculateNormalsJob.cpp` is not compiled. I have however no clue as to why. It is included in the project and Visual studio's IntelliSense has knowledge of the class and it's functions.

EDIT 2:

```
CalculateNormalsJob.h
CalculateNormalsJob(ResourceMap *state, JobScheduler *scheduler,  Job* listener, int scanNumber);


CalculateNormalsJob.cpp
CalculateNormalsJob::CalculateNormalsJob(ResourceMap *state, JobScheduler *scheduler, Job* listener, int scanNumber)
    : Job(state, scheduler, listener), scanNumber(scanNumber)
{
}


Call:
add(new CalculateNormalsJob(state,scheduler,this,scanNbr));
```

Comment: Are you actually linking with CaclulateNormalJobs.cpp?

Comment: Are you sure you have added the `CalculateNormalsJob.cpp` file that belongs to CalculateNormalsJob.h` to the project so that it actually gets compiled?

Comment: The "CalculateNormalsJob.cpp" file is included in the project and should be compiled

Comment: Maybe your declaration is different from your definition?

Comment: Nope, I have double and triple checked declaration and definition. Everything should be in order.

Comment: You need to provide the specific params in the code - `some params` isn't particularly helpful..

Comment: stupid question maybe, but you haven't inadvertently ticked the option at the individual file setting level for CalculateNormalsJob.cpp that says "Excluded from Build"? Otherwise suggest just removing the file from the project and the adding it back in. (As well as quitting and restarting visual studio.) You could try rebuilding the whole project from scratch, too.

Comment: @TooTone No I hadn't, but your answer led me to check the properties of the file `CalculateNormalsJob.cpp` and it turned out that it was created as a header file and thus it's "Item Type" setting was set to header file. When I changed the setting to C/C++ compiler it is compiled as it should! Thank You

Comment: @FredrikBagge consider posting that as an answer to your own question

Answer (score 0):

I checked the properties of the file CalculateNormalsJob.cpp (right click->properties) and it turned out that it was created as a header file and later renamed to .cpp, thus it's "Item Type" setting was set to header file. When I changed the setting to C/C++ compiler it is compiled as it should and the linker could find the external symbol.